# How can an element be added without being specified what kind of element it is?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When looking at a tutorial , I read this piece of code :

```
if (response.messages instanceof Object) {
  $.each(response.messages, function(index, value) {
    var id = $("#" + index);
    id
      .closest('.form-group')
      .after(value);
  });
});
```

So, it adds a message after each input element in a form. But I don't understand how can an element be added without being specified what kind of element it is, there are no tags anywhere for this element to be added.

Comment: it might not be an element. It could just be plain text. Can you provide a full working example?

Comment: it has an id, so I thought it's an element

Comment: `.after()` creates the element from the string `value`. `value` can be plaintext or html markup, jquery doesnt care about that.

Comment: @annie the `id` is not referring to the newly created element.

Comment: @N.Ivanov then what is it referring to?

Comment: The existing elements on the page. [Here's an example.](https://jsfiddle.net/wwge6qvu/6/)

Comment: As per your jsfiddle code, it doesn't add content after each input field as stated, it adds content after form-group div

Comment: @Andy In my code there is no input field with `id=0`or `1` . So I don't understand how can a message be added after an element with `id=0` if such an element doesn't exist.

Comment: Is the tutorial on-line? Perhaps you can share the link.

Comment: @Andy This is the link for the source code: http://www.mediafire.com/file/1d0bzqiqytjjryk/crud_datatables_codeigniter.tar

Comment: @Andy This is for the video series, if it helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjiYeAb_ZsQ&list=PLaSPP6wN3sqvXpVKdAChLk0FKZtybyUnV

Answer (score 0):

`response.messages` is iterated, and each item in that array is passed to jQuery `.after`, which accepts an HTML string.

The `index` parameter will be the index in the array of that element.

So if `response.messages` is `['<p>test</p>'];` there will be a single iteration where `<p>test</p>` is appended after `$('#0').closest('.form-group');`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/after/

**Similar to other content-adding methods such as .prepend() and .before(), .after() also supports passing in multiple arguments as input. Supported input includes DOM elements, jQuery objects, HTML strings, and arrays of DOM elements.**